# Python unittest - setUp warning: ResourceWarning

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am preparing my tests and I have one warning after running this script:

```
class TestForm(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        with open('test_json.json') as f:
            self.hd = json.load(f)

        self.reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
        self.result = {}
        for row in self.reader:
            key = row[0]
            self.result[key] = row[1:]

    def test_1(self):
        self.form = self.hd[0]['Customer'][0]['Information'][0]['Form']
        self.exp = self.result['Form1'][0]
        self.assertEqual(self.form, self.exp)

    def test_2(self):
        self.form = self.hd[1]['Customer'][0]['Information'][0]['Form']
        self.exp = self.result['Form2'][0]
        self.assertEqual(self.form, self.exp)
```

Error:

```
.C:\Program Files\Python\3.5.1\lib\unittest\suite.py:107: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.csv' mode='r' encoding='cp1250'>
  for index, test in enumerate(self):
```

The script is completed but this error is strange. I observed that it only occurs when this part is in the `setUp` function:

```
        with open('test_json.json') as f:
            self.hd = json.load(f)

        self.reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
        self.result = {}
        for row in self.reader:
            key = row[0]
            self.result[key] = row[1:]
```

When I use it outside of `TestForm`, there is no warning in the script. Should I move it back outside `class TestForm`, or even do it in different file?

Comment: You never close the csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code opens a CSV file and keeps it open forever:

```
self.reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
```

This is the "correct" way to do it:

```
with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
    self.reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    # use the file

# the file is closed here, when the context is closed
```

Another way is to open and close "manually":

```
csv_file = open('test.csv')
self.reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
# use the file

# when you are done, close the file:
csv_file.close()
```

It looks like you are never using `self.reader` after `setUp`, so this seems to be the best solution in your case:

```
def setUp(self):
    with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        self.result = {}
        for row in reader:
            key = row[0]
            self.result[key] = row[1:]

    # csv_file closes here; reader is not any longer available either
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot